# Find files and specify some to come first in playlist, and the rest in random order?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, pipe

The following code creates a list of the files in the directory and then shuffles them in a random order then spits out the file in a text document called list.txt

```
find *.EXT | sed 's:\ :\\\ :g' | sed 's/^/file /' | sort -R  > list.txt
```

Contents of the file would look something like this.

```
file filename_2.EXT
file filename_3.EXT
file filename_1.EXT
file filename_4.EXT
file filename_5.EXT
```

I would really like to know if it is possible to (very easily within terminal, on the command line) specify which filenames I want to see come first within list.txt, and then rest be random as normal, as the code above intends.

How would I be able to do this very easily on the command line and hopefully within this same exact line of code, or something else, doesn't matter, as long as it does what I am trying to achieve.

```
find *.EXT | sed 's:\ :\\\ :g' | sed 's/^/file /' | sort -R  > list.txt
```

It would maybe look something like:

*( this is just to understand what I am trying to achieve )*

```
find *.EXT | xsort --comefirstfiles=filename_3.EXT,filename_1.EXT | xsort --therest random | sed 's:\ :\\\ :g' | sed 's/^/file /' > list.txt
```

Is this possible? If not, what is the closest option to doing this within the same line as the "find" code?

Answer (score 1):

In zsh:

```
files=( **/*.EXT(oe'{REPLY=$RANDOM}') )
first=(input3.EXT input5.EXT)
printf 'file %s\n' ${first[@]} ${files:|first} > list.txt
```

The first line assigns an array of all the files you're looking for (recursively), but orders them randomly.

The second line assigns an array of filenames that you'd like to have *first* in the resulting list.

The third line prints the filenames out to list.txt (prepended with `"file "`; the two arguments are the `first` files followed by the rest of the `files` -- but the latter uses the array removal syntax `:|` to remove entries from "files" that exist in the array "first".

On this sample input:

```
$ tree .
.
├── input1.EXT
├── input2.EXT
├── input3.EXT
├── input4.EXT
├── input5.EXT
└── subdir
    └── subdirfile1.EXT
```

The first sample run is:

```
$ files=( **/*.EXT(oe'{REPLY=$RANDOM}') )
$ first=(input3.EXT input5.EXT)
$ printf 'file %s\n' ${first[@]} ${files:|first}
file input3.EXT
file input5.EXT
file subdir/subdirfile1.EXT
file input4.EXT
file input1.EXT
file input2.EXT
```

and a subsequent sample run is:

```
$ files=( **/*.EXT(oe'{REPLY=$RANDOM}') )
$ first=(input3.EXT input5.EXT)
$ printf 'file %s\n' ${first[@]} ${files:|first}
file input3.EXT
file input5.EXT
file input1.EXT
file input2.EXT
file subdir/subdirfile1.EXT
file input4.EXT
```